# Mac Disk-Utility input/output error

Tags: macos, dvd, ripping, disk-utility

a couple of other people have posted about this but my specific problem has not been addressed.  For months I have been backing up DVDs and home movies with no problem then all of a sudden I get an "input/output" error.  Yes I have cleaned the disks. Actually I have tried 8 different ones - they are not all bad so its obviously my computer.  I have done a scan and cleaned up the HD a bit just in case but nothing is helping.

I don't want to download other programs since this one works but seems to be having a problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to download other programs since this one works but seems to be having a problem.

I'd say that qualifies as "not working".

An input/output error may be due to the burner failing. Did anything happen recently that may have caused damage to the DVD drive (shocks, spills, heavy things on top of it if it's a laptop)?

What about reads? Can you play back one of your backed-up DVDs without skips or issues?